# Filter element json WCF Data Services

Tags: c#, json, wcf

In my code here, I consume WCF rest using dataGridView, and by the code below, I want to filter conditions to show only events in last 5 days, so I need to add filter in the link, but I don't know how.

My problem :
* how add filter to show event last 5 days.

My code:

```
public void  button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            dataGridView1.DataSource = GetRESTData("http://localhost:55495/EventService.svc/GetAllEvents");
        }
        catch (WebException webex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Es gab so ein Schlamassel! ({0})", webex.Message);
        }
    }

    private JArray GetRESTData(string uri)
    {
        var webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(uri);
        var webResponse = (HttpWebResponse)webRequest.GetResponse();
        var reader = new StreamReader(webResponse.GetResponseStream());
        string s = reader.ReadToEnd();
        return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JArray>(s);
    }
```

Image of dataGridView
[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you can see the inside of the array you can use linq to filter 
I think your best bat would be to create a class and bind it to class

but you can try this

```
JObject eventob= JObject.Parse(s);

var events =
       (from p in (JArray)eventob["ParentObjectYouHave"]
        orderby (DateTime?)p.["Start_Date"] descending
        select p).Take(5);
```

Comment: somthing expected hete "p.["St" with the "."

Answer (score 0):

because I am working with WCF, and there is a quety that give me the result, so I modify the query and I get my result

```
DateTime today = DateTime.Today.AddHours(+12);
DateTime lastday = DateTime.Today.AddDays(-5);
var query = (from a in se.Events
                     where a.start_date <= today && a.start_date >= lastday || a.end_date <= today && a.end_date >= lastday
                     orderby a.start_date
                     select a).Distinct();
```